# How can I save a whole MediaWiki wiki without shell access?

Tags: windows, mediawiki, wiki

I'd like to save a whole wiki site (not Wikipedia, but a smaller wiki), with all of its text and media. I'm using a Windows system. I'd prefer the simplest solution.

Comment: Also, you'll have to be more specific. What kind of Wiki, what software is it based on? Where's the wiki running and how can you access it? Only HTTP or do you also have access to the filesystem and/or database?

Comment: I don't have a specifict wiki in mind. I'm looking for a solution which works on wikis based on mediawiki, to which I only have HTTP access to.

Comment: Well, MediaWiki *is* a specific wiki software, and by far not the only one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [dumpgenerator.py](https://github.com/WikiTeam/wikiteam/blob/master/dumpgenerator.py) from WikiTeam e.g. to save complete XML histories and images:

```
python dumpgenerator.py http://wiki.domain.org --xml --images
```